# "COPY FROM table" mismatch column with .csv file

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to import data from a .csv file into a created table via pgadmin.

Summary:

- There are 18 columns.
  [.csv file viewed in MS Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2EZ.png)
  [table columns in pgadmin navigation pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CPcE.png)
- The original data was an .xlsx which is converted into a .csv via MS Excel's *Export*.
- The column "EvaluationID" is added by me in Excel to act as a primary key for importing.
- The dates are in ISO8601 (i.e.YYYY/MM/DD).
- I used pgadmin navigation pane to import instead of using the query tool.

Error:
[process watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEWKd.png)

- The value "Arlington" belongs in the column "AccountCity". Pgadmin thinks it is in the column "AccountState".
- This means there is an offset of one column between the .csv and the postgresql table.
- Column "AccountState" constraint is set to "character" with length "2" because state values are in abbreviated form (e.g. Arizona -> AZ).

**Question:**
**- How do I make sure the columns match?**

I checked to see if:

- The column names on the .csv file and in the database table are the same.
- The # of commas in the .csv file is 17 per line, and thus means 18 columns.

I also tried:

- Naming every single column via query tool code. See code below.

**COPY premiums_data(EvaluationID,EvaluationDate,AccountNumber,AccountName,AccountStreetNumber,AccountStreetname,AccountStreetSuffix,AccountCity,AccountState,AccountUnderwriter,PolicyNumber,PolicyType,PolicyEffectiveDate,PolicyExpirationDate,LineofBusiness,ExposureBase,ExposureBound,PremiumBound)
FROM 'C:\Users\Nacho\OneDrive\Data Tools Practice\Personal Projects\Project2_Combined(Edited)Premium_Data_Group Project Dataset Group 6.csv'
CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';**

- Pgadmin returns [process watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcVUD.png)
- Pgadmin now thinks the first column does not exist.

Comment: Please try to paste text, not pictures of text. The error messages are easily copyable, and so is the CSV header line. The table definition can also be displayed and copied as text. A sample line from the file would also be helpful - if there's sensitive data, it can be replaced with random values of similar type/format.

Comment: @Zegarek Thank you very much for the advice. This is my first ever post on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is due to the `AccountStreetSuffix` being the 7th column of the file while your table definition and your `copy` column list put it last. Everything shifted to the left because of that and misplaced `city` into `suffix`, `state` into `city` and `underwriter` into `state`. I'm guessing `Arlington` was in both `city` and `underwriter`, and you assumed the first one.

The second error is because your `copy` command column list doesn't use double quotes around column names that are case-sensitive: `"EvaluationID"` is not the same as `EvaluationID`. The former is interpreted as case-sensitive identifier, the latter is folded to lowercase, which is why you can see it end up as lowercase `evaluationid` in the error message. You need to either double-quote your identifiers everywhere or nowhere in your code, unless they are all lowercase regardless. If you created the table columns using the double quotes, use them in the `COPY` column list as well.

Comment: I corrected the COPY FROM column order and put "" over each column, as you mentioned. It works perfectly!

There is another housekeeping question. It seems that created columns in a pgsql table cannot be rearranged, as suggested by other posts. Do I have to create an entirely new table? 
Would the only other workaround be creating a VIEW with the desired column order?

Comment: That's correct. You'd have to drop and re-add columns of the table until you reach the desired order, or create another one and move the data, or set up a view.